# How I can specify GraphQL query for Apollo Client and get items which property has an occurrence of the appropriate string

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I did not work with GraphQL  before the last days. I use Apollo Client with `graphql-tag`. Now I can get the list of cities from a server with this query:

```
query {
    cities(country:countryName, limit:30){
      id
      name
  }    
}
```

But I want to get only the cities which names (`name` property) have an occurrence of the string that user typed. It should work like autocomplete. For example when user type `san` I want to get array of objects for `San Francisco, San Jose, San Juan...`. Is it possible to do it on the client side, or I should to ask the backend developer for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `country` arguments should be a variable and it'll compute from the component's props.

```
query ($country: String) {
  cities(country: $country, limit: 30) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Your input should sit in the component's parent which will pass down the value through the `country` prop.

Check out [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/812yp8jpk2?module=%2FApp.js) sandbox for an example. You can see the schema and resolvers [here](https://launchpad.graphql.com/xnjzxw0n8l)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for examples.